# How do I create a Doxygen Alias to mimic the @param behavior?

Tags: alias, doxygen, param

I want to create an alias of @param for global variables used within a function. I'd like to specify it like this:

```
@global[in] global_var_name    more textual description
@global[in] global_var_name2   some more text
@global[in/out] name_var_3     more text
@global[out] name_var_4        more text
```

I've created an alias using this:

```
ALIASES = "global=\xrefitem global \"Global\" \"Globals\" "
```

however, the HTML produced does not generate a table similar to @param. Does anyone know how to alias @param to generate a new table below the param table, or as consolation, append the globals to the @param table with "global in" in the square brackets instead of "in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply on the [doxygen users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/28570503/). Here is their answer. I haven't had a chance to try it.

```
ALIASES = "global{1}=@param [global \1]"
```